# How do you select which address the LDAP client binds to using OpenLDAP API?

Tags: c++, c, openldap

Is there a way using the OpenLDAP API to set a particular network interface address to be used for socket bind on the LDAP client on a multi homed machine; like you do with the LDAP_OPT_SOCKET_BIND_ADDRESSES option with Microsoft's LDAP client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by creating and binding and connecting the socket yourself and then calling ldap_init_fd() to turn it into an LDAP connection.

Comment: I am familiar with BSD Sockets and WinSock but I am new to the OpenLDAP libraries. I notice that ldap_init_fd() takes a ber_socket_t. I assume that there is a function similar to socket() to create a ber_socket_t; but I haven't been able to find it. Could you provide sample code that does this or point me to some.

Comment: No idea. I assumed it was just a socket FD. There's a *man* page for lber_sockbuf that alludes to it, cryptically enough.

Answer (score -1):

You choose the host and port of the server you want and use `ldap_open(host, port)`

Comment: Deprecated, and you haven't answered the question.

Comment: I see from the man page that ldap_open() and ldap_init() have been deprecated in favor of ldap_initialize() which accepts a comma or whitespace delinited list of URIs to LDAP servers.  Although I have not used this function, it would appear to satisfy the "multi-homed" server requirement of the user.  It also appears the actual connection occurs not on the call to ldap_initialize() but on the first use of the connection (probably ldap_bind()).

Comment: It doesn't satisfy the requirement for the client to bind to a specific IP address before connecting, which is what the question is actually about. He hasn't said a word about a 'multi-homed server requirement'. His question is about a client.

Comment: then I misunderstood what he meant by "LDAP client on a multi homed machine"... What IS a "multi homed machine"..?

Comment: A host with multiple NICs. In some obscure circumstances you need to bind a socket to a local address to ensure that its traffic goes out via that NIC. This is what he is asking about.